# I can't get rlang1.0.6 to install, and ggplot install says it needs version 1.0.6

Tags: rlang

I can't get rlang1.0.6 to install, and ggplot2 install says it needs version 1.0.6.
I am guessing 1.0.6 requires a newer version of R, but the version available when I installed RStudio is 3.6.1, and I tried donwnloding the newer version a,d I got all kinds of error messages so I reinstalled Ananconda and Rstudio.
This is the error message I get:

Warning in install.packages :
download of package ‘rlang’ failed

> install.packages("rlang")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
rlang 0.4.11  1.1.1              TRUE

Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/rlang_0.4.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1224139 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked